# Google Places API - French Regions

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I'm the owner of a job board. In our categories, we divide by the French Regions and we're currently using the Google Places API to do so.

Unfortunately, since July 2016, the names of somes French Regions has changed and the Google Places API hasn't been updated since.

Do you have an idea on who to contact or how to change it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should report a data issue following this document:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045?hl=en&ref_topic=3093612

Hope this helps!